# Black and white to color working weirdly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I'm working on a tumblr theme where the photos load in black and white, and once you hover over them, they turn to color. The black and white to color plugin is working perfectly, but when I display the photos as block to remove the annoying few-pixel margin below photos by default, the photos in their black and white state have a few pixels of the photo in color, and when you hover over them, they do turn from black and white to color, but for some odd reason the photos also get zoomed in by a few pixels? I don't understand why this is happening and I'm not sure how to fix it, if anyone could help that would be great! This is the theme > http://jamescharless.tumblr.com/

The jQuery

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.bwWrapper').BlackAndWhite({
            hoverEffect: true,
            webworkerPath: 'js/',
            onImageReady:function(img){
            }
        });
    });
```

The HTML

```
<a href="#" class="bwWrapper">
                    <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" class="entryphoto">
                </a>
```

And the CSS

```
div#container div.entry {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 16.666666666666666666666666666%;
    display: block;
}

div#container div.entry .entryphoto {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% important;
    display: block;
}

a.bwWrapper { margin: 0 !important; border: 0 !important; }
```

Comment: please post CSS, HTML, and JS here for preservation otherwise if your tumblr theme changes later the solution won't make sense.

Comment: @abc123 I updated it with code.

Comment: Just had quick poke-around in the chrome inspector. It looks like it is stretching the images or something. Are you using a separate plugin for the layout of the images / how they resize?

Comment: @BenjaminKaiser No, the width of the posts are defined in the CSS.

Comment: See there is your problem. If you use the chrome inspector (if you don't know how to do this please look it up) by right-clicking on one of the images when it is not black and white, you will see that it inherits a css property from the class `.entryphoto` to be `width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important`. If you set the style for width and height (with `!important`) on the un-black&white photo to be the same as the black&white element next to it, it will work perfectly. I personally don't see why it creates two versions of the photo instead of just one and toggle the `greyscale(x%)`.

Comment: @BenjaminKaiser I don't understand what you're telling me to do here..

Comment: @JamesCharless, DW. I see you got it working anyway.